# Kali Linux VM 2020 after upgrade converted all text to some kind of hex

Tags: kali-linux, hex

I am doing some training with the OSCP shipped Kali VM. It was working fine and I got around to upgrading all packages and after I did, I get this problem. I cant even navigate to some kind of settings menu to try and turn in off or revert it back. I am running VMWare Pro and im not seeing any settings to turn this off. Any assistance would be most appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Hex...not Kex. My mistake. I cant edit it.

Comment: here is the edit link https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/586271/edit

Comment: that font has characters shaped like that so you can see the ASCII code of each letter ... change the system font to something legible ... http://www.asciitable.com/mobile/ ...